# Jansson on Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, jansson

I am trying to test Jansson on Xcode 7.3.1.  I installed according to the instructions, then used cMake when that didn't work, which also didn't work.  I think Xcode is having trouble finding the Jansson library.  I have modified the project header and library paths in many different ways, after extensive suggestions from searching out this problem.  Xcode *is* able to find the header. Note also that I am able to install Jansson and run it in Eclipse. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is the error log from Xcode:

Ld /Users/corrychapman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JanssonDev-dispcmnteuwiedaiazlbkwtztfcu/Build/Products/Debug/JanssonDev normal x86_64
    cd /Users/corrychapman/Desktop/jansson-2.11/JanssonDev
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/corrychapman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JanssonDev-dispcmnteuwiedaiazlbkwtztfcu/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -L/Users/corrychapman/Desktop/jansson-2.11/JanssonDev -F/Users/corrychapman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JanssonDev-dispcmnteuwiedaiazlbkwtztfcu/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/corrychapman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JanssonDev-dispcmnteuwiedaiazlbkwtztfcu/Build/Intermediates/JanssonDev.build/Debug/JanssonDev.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JanssonDev.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/corrychapman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JanssonDev-dispcmnteuwiedaiazlbkwtztfcu/Build/Intermediates/JanssonDev.build/Debug/JanssonDev.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JanssonDev_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/corrychapman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JanssonDev-dispcmnteuwiedaiazlbkwtztfcu/Build/Products/Debug/JanssonDev

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_json_array_get", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_json_array_size", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_json_delete", referenced from:
      _json_decref in main.o
  "_json_loads", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_json_object_get", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_json_string_value", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags:  -ljansson